# How to compile Linux kernel code on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, linux-kernel

I want to compile and later modify a Linux kernel code but I cannot do it by installing and running separate Linux system  like  Ubuntu and then compiling this kernel on linux system as I am not able to work on full fledged Linux system(Laptop hardware problems).I want to do it on Windows 7.Is there a way that I can do it?

Comment: Seems a bit offtopic for StackOverflow. Not sure where you would put it. Going to be tricky to do this needless to say.

Comment: Run linux in a virtual machine, compile from there?

Answer (score 8):

The Linux kernel source tree has different files in some directories whose names only differ in capitalization, so unpacking the source tree would have to happen in a directory where the POSIX compatibility mode was active. Furthermore, you need a cross compiler targetting Linux, and an appropriate shell environment.

It can be done within the Cygwin environment if so desired, but I suspect it is significantly easier to run a Linux virtual machine, or CoLinux.

Answer (score 2):

i Think you are talking about [this](http://sysprogs.com/VisualKernel/tutorials/vmware/) have a look on this site they provide a way to compile and modify and infact build a new kernel in Visual Studio hope it will help you